# Partir en voyage pour la / une journée

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

J'ai croisé une connaissance dans la rue, je lui ai demandé :

> Vous partez en voyage ?

Elle m'a répondu :

> Oui, pour **la** journée.

Donc, l'article défini signifie qu'elle parle d'aujourd'hui. Mais elle aurait aussi pu dire "pour **une** journée" (une, pas deux), n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: Pour vous c'est quoi: vous partez? Le jour même ou un autre jour? En tout cas, une journée n'est pas la journée, qui implique le même jour.

Answer (score 2):

La personne a des bagages avec elle qui laissent supposer un départ en voyage.

> **Pour la journée** : Je pars ce matin, je serai de retour ce soir.

> **Pour une journée** : Je pars aujourd'hui. Je serai ailleurs une journée entière. Je serai donc à priori de retour demain.

- ***La** journée*: article défini, on indique qu'il s'agit d'une journée précise. Comme il n'y a pas d'autre indication, ce ne peut être que la journée qui est en train de se dérouler: aujourd'hui. Si on dit *Je pars pour la journée du patrimoine à Paris*, il s'agit du jour correspondant à cet événement, pas forcément aujourd'hui donc.
- ***Une** journée*: article indéfini mais comme la personne est en train de partir, il ne s'agit pas de n'importe quelle journée. ***Un*** a alors plutôt son sens arithmétique, une journée de 24 heures qui commence.

Comment: Merci. Les articles, c'est vraiment compliqué :)